# File type based indentation in Kate

Tags: kate

So after quite a lot of searching and frustration I'm here to ask how to do one of the most basic (or so I thought) things in a modern text editor. I want to set a different indentation for different files types. I almost all the time edit `javascript`+`HTML/XML`+`python` together, and cannot have a fixed `4-spaces` or `2-spaces` indentation.

I tried setting the indentation mode for different files. However, I cannot find a way to change the number of spaces to indent for each mode. In `Settings->Configure Kate->Editing->Indentation`, I can set the `Default Indentation Mode` and select the number of spaces to indent. But there's no way to change the **number of spaces to indent** for each mode.

#### Temporary solution:

add,

```
<!-- kate: indent-width 2; -->
```

at the beginning of every XML file. Which is quite annoying.

---

Obviously I want to know if there's a easier way to do it, but if there's no way to do it from the UI, I would love if someone can help me cook up a solution.

I found [this](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=160034) bug report (filed 5years ago), where the person mentions something like

> The current workaround is to type "kate: indent-mode " into Variables under filetype properties.

I don't know where to find this `filetype properties` :/ or even if it exists.

Comment: `Settings → Configure Kate... → Editor Component → Open/Save → Modes & Filetypes`

Comment: see, you can select the `indentation **mode**` there, but the problem is no way to change the number of spaces to indent for each mode.

Comment: You should be able to select `Markup/XML` as `Filetype:` and enter `kate: indent-width 2;` into `Variables:`.

Comment: OH `varibles:` GOD DAMN IT I DIDN'T SEE :)))) thx.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Being a Kate developer myself, the answer is indeed as discussed in the comments. Each `mode` / `filetype` can be configured individually through document variables in `Settings → Configure Kate → Editor Component → Open/Save → Modes & Filetypes`. Therein, select your desired filetype, e.g. `Scripts/Python`. Then select your preferred indentation mode. To set the indent width, you can click on the little tool-button next to the `Variables` line edit, which will popup a list with all document variables available. Set `indent-width` to e.g. `4` and close the popup. The `Variables` line edit then contains the string `kate: indent-width 4:`, which is exactly the same string that you can also embedd directly into your document, if wanted.