# Kate Editor: force Python files to use spaces instead of tabs

Tags: python, kde, text-formatting, editors, kate

For Python files, I must use spaces for indenting. My default Kate editor setting uses tabs. I don't want to change the default, but I want to configure the proper settings for Python files.

I found an answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134424/15010) that gives the basic steps:

1. In Kate `Settings → Configure Kate → Editor Component → Open/Save → Modes & Filetypes`.
2. Therein, select your desired filetype, e.g. Scripts/Python.
3. Click on the little tool-button next to the `Variables` line edit.
4. In the dialog that opens, scroll down until you find:

   - replace-tabs-save
   - replace-tabs

In those options, I checked the box (to override the default setting) and selected `true` from the drop down list. I "OK'd" the changes and came back to editing my Python file. **However, the changes I made are not having any effect.**

What did I do wrong?