# How to set default color and font schemes for different katepart applications

Tags: kde, editors, kate

katepart is the base for many KDE editing tasks and I mostly use it 
1) as the editing component of kile, the LaTex editor, and
2) as standalone kate or kwrite for editing text files such as HTML or configuration files, simple text notes etc.

These different tasks require different fonts: in kile I prefer a serif font, because I work on long texts with it; in HTML or config files I need monospace fonts, because of column matching.

But if I change the default color&font scheme of the editor in kile (by creating and editing a scheme and setting it as default) this also changes the font&color for kwrite and all other kateparts applications. If I change it again in kwrite, also kile will adopt this new setting upon next start.

Is there a way to get different default settings for different katepart applications?
If not, what is the use of the "Default schema for kile" setting in Settings>Configure Kile>Editor>Font&Color Schemas then?

Setup: kate 17.12.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Katepart can be configured in different ways, as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84371/how-do-i-make-kate-indent-with-spaces-on-python-files-but-use-tabs-for-text-file?rq=1) or in the [Kate Handbook](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/katepart/config-variables.html).

Maybe the easiest way for the problem here is to configure settings for the LaTeX filetype:

Go to Settings > Configure Kate > Open/Save > Modes & Filetypes tab. Choose the Markup/LaTeX filetype and change the modeline to: 
    kate: font [your-serif-font]; font-size [your-preferred-font-size]

Whatever else you set up as your font in kate, kwrite etc. will be used for everything but TeX-documents.